# Symfony 4 and FOSJsRoutingBundle OK in dev env, but KO in prod env (Routing is not defined)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

From symfony 4, I used the bundle jsrouting for get symfony route path from JS code. 
In `dev` environment all works fine, but when I set the symfony configuration to `prod` mod I get this error when I load a page where one of my javascript scrips use jsrouting :

[image]

(error occured in a custom javascript file `global.js` used by my page)

My twig file contains theses lines :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/js/us/builder/global.js') }}"></script>
```

- I set the variable `APP_ENV` to `dev` in .env file : when I load the page, from the browser debugger I see :

[image]

- But if I set the variable `APP_ENV` to `prod` in .env file : when I load the page, from the browser debugger I see :

[image]

I don't understand why when I go to `prod` mode, these two lines :

```
<script src="/*****/public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js"></script>
<script src="/*****/public/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>
```

are missing...and this is why I got the error "Routing is not defined", because "Routing" is defined in the router.js file .

I don't understand why theses lines are missing when Symfony is in the `prod` environment

The content of my config file `/myproject/config/bundles.php` :

```
<?php

return [
    //...
    FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

**EDIT** The output of some console commands :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at your var directories, sub-directories permission and owner.

```sh
php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer
chmod -R 777 var/log
```

put the right owner for the prod directory:

```
cache/prod
```